# Algebraic manipulation from notable limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I have no idea of how to solve the following:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{3x}$$

I know about the notable special limit $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$, and I know that I have to do some algebraic manipulation and change what I have above to the notable one, but I can't quite see how.

Comment: you did make a } to much at the very end

Comment: So, in general, if you know the $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ what is $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{3}$?

Comment: Um, your "notable special limit" is wrong. $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$$ not $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I already edited it. Also, thanks for fixing my LaTeX issue whomever did it, the second limit I already put it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the fact that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$$

We can simply rewrite your limit as

$$\frac13\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

Which is $\frac13 \cdot1 = \frac13$.

**Alternative**: note that this is of form $\frac00$, and both functions are continuous in the neighborhood of $0$, so we can use [L'Hopital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), which allows us to rewrite our limit as

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x}{3} = \frac13 $$

**Alternative 2**: use the Taylor Series for $e^x$ around $0$.

Recall that $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ Writing out the first few terms yields $1+x+O(x^2)$ where $O(x^2)$ represents the higher order terms on or past the order of $x^2$. Since we are in a neighborhood around $0$, note that these higher order terms all go to $0$ since $x$ is going to $0$.

Thus our limit now is 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+x)-1}{3x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{3x} = \frac13$$

Comment: where does this fact come from?

Comment: Yes, it's indeterminate, which means (or so I thought) that I can't do several limit properties such as lim(a*b) = lim a * lim b.

Comment: I added a few alternatives. @Alex, he noted the limit in his question (though he originally mistook the limit to be $0$ and not $1$), so I assumed he had knowledge of it. I added the usual method using L'Hopital.

Answer (score 1):

A handy thing to know is that $e^x = 1 + x + O(x^2) \approx 1 + x $ for $x$ near $0$.

Using this, you will see immediately that the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Being a bit more rigorous, you may notice that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{3x} = \frac{1}{3} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x - e^0}{x} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx} e^x \big|_{x=0} $$

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the limit that you have provided is indeterminate. 
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{3x}
&=\frac{e^0-1}{3(0)}
=\frac{0}{0}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, you can use L'Hopital's Rule which states:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Therefore, let $f(x)$ be $e^x -1$ and let $g(x)$ be $3x$ and apply L'Hopital's Rule.

$$\begin{align}
&\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \\
&\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x}{3}\\
&\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^0}{3}
= \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$. Note, that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$.